# Exporting images and font-awesome icons from seperate js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, font-awesome

I've read a lot of solutions on how to store images in an array of objects. I did every solution and none of them worked for me. Maybe I'm missing a cast?

Images are stored in `src` folder.

I've tried to `export default`, but unfortunately it did not solve the problem.

Exporting part(MenuList.js):

```
import burgerImg from '../images/menu-images/burger-menu2.png'
import pizzaImg from '../images/menu-images/pizza-menu1.png'
import kebabImg from '../images/menu-images/kebab-menu1.png'
import {FaHamburger} from 'react-icons/fa'
import {FaPizzaSlice} from 'react-icons/fa'
import {GiMeal} from 'react-icons/gi'


export const MenuList = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Burgers',
        img: burgerImg,
        icon: FaHamburger
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Pizzas',
        img: pizzaImg,
        iconImg: FaPizzaSlice
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Kebabs',
        img: kebabImg,
        icon: GiMeal
    }
]
```

Importing part(Menu.js):

```
import {MenuList} from './MenuList'

 state = {
    menu: MenuList
}
   {this.state.menu.map(item => {
               return <MenuItem key={item.id} itemInfo={item}/>
   })}
```

MenuItem.js:

```
export default function MenuItem({itemInfo}) {
return (
    <div>
        {itemInfo.name}
        {itemInfo.img}
        {itemInfo.icon}
    </div>
)
}
```

And then I'm trying to load everything from single component like that:

```
export default function HomeMenu() {
return (
    <div>
        <h1>Menu</h1>
        <Menu></Menu>
    </div>
)
}
```

I'm mapping through every element of my list and passing the elements to another component, but the problem is that my images and font-awesome icons aren't loading.

When I run the project or refresh it, I get the following result:

```
Burgers/static/media/burger-menu2.d3dca9de.png
```

The console outputs this:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
```

Dev tools panel elements section of images shows this:

[image]

Folder structure:

[image]

Am I missing a cast about something? I viewed a lot of stack about importing/exporting images, but none of the solutions worked for me.

Comment: whats the error? 404's? how are you serving the built files? For it to be `burger-menu2.d3dca9de.png` its working, but looks like you dont have in place something to serve the images from the dist

Comment: What does your dev tools elements panel show for the `src` for images. And the fonts, how is it being show in the elements panel. ? Can you provide a screenshot of them ??

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Images are part of src folder inside images/menu-images folder. My components are part of src folder inside components folder. I've updated the post.

Comment: @Panther Fonts aren't being showed in the panel at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `MenuItem.js` as,

```
export default function MenuItem({itemInfo}) {
return (
    <div>
        {itemInfo.name}
        <img src={itemInfo.img} alt='' />
        {itemInfo.icon}
    </div>
)
}
```

To fix icon issue, pass the component as `jsx` in the object. Modify as:

```
export const MenuList = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Burgers',
        img: burgerImg,
        icon: <FaHamburger /> //jsx
    },
...
```

`jsx` is just javascript with some syntactical sugar.

Comment: Thank you. The images are being rendered now, but font-awesome icons are still not visible.

Comment: can you show structure of `react-icons` ? They might be components or something else instead of image files. Add screenshot to question.

Comment: https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/ This is how I implement the icons. I just haveto install the dependency via npm and import whatever icon I need

Comment: Dev console now outputs this warning. `index.js:1 Warning: Invalid value for prop src on <img> tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM.`. It doesn't look that this is the correct way to render images in the DOM

Comment: @T.Jony Please try according to the updated answer.

Comment: `'React' must be in scope when using JSX`. This obviously doesn't work because JSX needs to return something. You can't use JSX like in your second code example

Comment: Try importing react in `MenuItem.js`. Add `import React from 'react';` in the file.

Comment: Yes, react is imported in the `MenuItem.js`

Comment: I've imported the react in the `MenuList.js` where I'm storing array of objects and It works. But I don't think this is the proper way to do it. Big thanks for the help!

Comment: It's great that it worked. Generally `jsx` is passed through `props.children`. But its okay to use `jsx` as part of object as in your case.